# Assembly Code: If this code runs from its start until the endpoint

Tags: assembly

```
0x40106e    <main+30>:      mov    $0x0,%edx
0x401073    <main+35>:      mov    $0x0,%ecx
0x401078    <main+40>:      cmp    $0x9,%ecx
0x40107b    <main+43>:      jle    0x40107f <main+47>
0x40107d    <main+45>:      jmp    0x401084 <main+52>
0x40107f    <main+47>:      add    %ecx,%edx
0x401081    <main+49>:      inc    %ecx
0x401082    <main+50>:      jmp    0x401078 <main+40>
0x401084    <main+52>:      // endpoint
```

the value in register ecx & edx will be? Can someone help me step through this program.
Also, how can i run this on ideone.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to this, you should annotate each line with what happens in human-readable language. Also, don't be shy to change labels to make things easier to follow.

On my part, I found it obvious that `<main+40>` is a loop condition and that `<main+47>` is the loop body. I figured this was a loop because the code jumps back (code that only jumps forward cannot loop). Since `<main+40>` tests `ecx` and jumps accordingly, I guessed that this is where the loop condition is evaluated. This leaves `<main+47>` to be the loop body.

```
            mov    $0x0,%edx    ; %edx = 0
            mov    $0x0,%ecx    ; %ecx = 0
loop_test:  cmp    $0x9,%ecx    ; compare %ecx to 9 (see jumps below)
            jle    loop_body    ; jump to loop_body if %ecx <= 9
            jmp    endpoint     ; jump to endpoint otherwise
loop_body:  add    %ecx,%edx    ; %edx += %ecx
            inc    %ecx         ; %ecx++
            jmp    loop_test    ; return to comparison
endpoint:                       ; endpoint
```

You can then write C code that does the same thing:

```
    int ecx = 0;
    int edx = 0;

loop_test:
    if (ecx <= 9)
    {
        goto loop_body;
    }
    goto endpoint;

loop_body:
    edx += ecx;
    ecx++;
    goto loop_test;

endpoint:
    return;
```

The astute reader will notice the strange similarity this bears to a for loop.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    total += i;
}
```

If you don't know about an instruction, you should [look it up](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) (disclaimer: I am the maintainer of that resource).